# How to configure relevance of term on Haystack with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have set up a Djangoproject and now want to include a non-database-search with haystack and elasticsearch as backend. In the Indexes I used EdgeNgramFields for text. Everything works fine, except that the search gives too many results. I have read the documentation on http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ but could not find a possibility to set a relevance-option.

In the part about Boost they are talking about a score. So basicly I want to have the ability to define a minimum score. But I cannot find an explanation of the field score on results.

What I have missed? Is there somewhere the possibility to do, what I am talking about?

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing you exact mapping and sample data it will be difficult to tell you why your search returns too many results. However, I assume that your edgengram tokenizer uses a very small starting size of substrings like 1 or 2. With such a setting there are a lot of matches, e.g. if you have the following phrase with a starting size of 1:

```
a quick brown fox
```

It will be tokenized the following way:

```
a q qu qui quick b br bro brow brown f fo fox
```

Which might produce a lot of matches for a query. As a solution you might use another starting size and fuzzy search to find similar results.

But first, please provide your exact data mapping, sample data and your queries.

Below an example custom backend is provided. The crucial part are the custom types on the bottom of the custom config part and the build_schema function.

Example Custom Backend Config:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'myservice.apps.search.search_backends.CustomElasticSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack_prod',
        'TIMEOUT': 60,
    },
}
```

Example Custom Backend:

```
from django.conf import settings
from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import ElasticsearchSearchBackend, ElasticsearchSearchEngine
from haystack.fields import NgramField
from haystack.models import SearchResult
import requests
import pyelasticsearch

class CustomElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):
    #DEFAULT_ANALYZER = "snowball"
    DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
        'settings': {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "ngram_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                        "filter": ["haystack_ngram"]
                    },
                    "edgengram_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                        "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "haystack_edgengram"]
                    },
                    "full_text": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                    },
                    "partial_text": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding", "text_ngrams"]
                    },
                    "partial_text_front": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding", "text_edgengrams_front"]
                    },
                    "partial_text_back": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "asciifolding", "text_edgengrams_back"]
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "haystack_ngram_tokenizer": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 15,
                    },
                    "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer": {
                        "type": "edgeNGram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 15,
                        "side": "front"
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "haystack_ngram": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 15
                    },
                    "haystack_edgengram": {
                        "type": "edgeNGram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 15
                    },
                    "text_ngrams": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 50
                    },
                    "text_edgengrams_front": {
                        "type": "edgeNGram",
                        "side": "front",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 50
                    },
                    "text_edgengrams_back": {
                        "type": "edgeNGram",
                        "side": "back",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 50
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def makemapping(self, index_fieldname):
        return {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
                index_fieldname: {"type": "string",
                                  "analyzer": "partial_text",
                                  "include_in_all": True},
                "full": {"type": "string",
                         "analyzer": "full_text",
                         "include_in_all": True},
                "partial": {"type": "string",
                            "index_analyzer": "partial_text",
                            "search_analyzer": "full_text",
                            "include_in_all": True},
                "partial_front": {"type": "string",
                                  "index_analyzer": "partial_text_front",
                                  "search_analyzer": "full_text",
                                  "include_in_all": True},
                "partial_back": {"type": "string",
                                 "index_analyzer": "partial_text_back",
                                 "search_analyzer": "full_text",
                                 "include_in_all": True}
            }
        }

    def emailmapping(self, index_fieldname):
        return {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
                index_fieldname: {"type": "string",
                                  "analyzer": "standard"},
                "keyword": {"type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "keyword",
                            "include_in_all": True},
            }
        }

    def makequery(self, param):
        fuzzy_param = param[1:-1] if len(param) > 2 else param
        query = {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        # TODO: bei fuzzy suche funktionniert die autocompletion nicht
                        {"fuzzy_like_this": {"fields": ["text.full"], "like_text": fuzzy_param, "max_query_terms": 12}},
                        {"fuzzy": {"text": {"value": fuzzy_param, "min_similarity": 0.6}}},
                        #{"fuzzy": {"email": fuzzy_param}},
                        #{"fuzzy": {"first_name": fuzzy_param}},
                        #{"fuzzy": {"last_name": fuzzy_param}},
                        # this for the case first name is a CharField
                        #{"match": {"first_name": {"query": param, "boost": 10}}},
                        #{"match": {"last_name": {"query": param, "boost": 10}}},
                        # email
                        #{"text": {"first_name": {"boost": 5, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}},
                        {"text": {"email": {"boost": 5, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"email.keyword": {"boost": 10, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"contact_email": {"boost": 5, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"contact_email.keyword": {"boost": 10, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"contact_email2": {"boost": 5, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"contact_email2.keyword": {"boost": 10, "query": param}}},
                        # first_name
                        #{"text": {"first_name": {"boost": 5, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}},
                        {"text": {"first_name.partial": {"boost": 5, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"first_name.partial_front": {"boost": 10, "query": param}}},
                        #{"text": {"first_name.partial_back": {"boost": 4, "query": param}}},
                        # last_name
                        #{"text": {"last_name": {"boost": 5, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}},
                        {"text": {"last_name.partial": {"boost": 5, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"last_name.partial_front": {"boost": 10, "query": param}}},
                        #{"text": {"last_name.partial_back": {"boost": 4, "query": param}}},
                        # company
                        #{"text": {"company": {"boost": 5, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}},
                        {"text": {"company.partial": {"boost": 5, "query": param}}},
                        {"text": {"company.partial_front": {"boost": 10, "query": param}}},
                        #{"text": {"company.partial_back": {"boost": 4, "query": param}}},
                        # text
                        # ngrams with less accurate results
                        #{"text": {"text": {"boost": 1, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}},
                        {"text": {"text.partial": {"boost": 3, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}},
                        {"text": {"text.partial_front": {"boost": 5, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}},
                        #{"text": {"text.partial_back": {"boost": 5, "query": param, "type": "phrase"}}}
                    ]
                }
            },
            "size": 100
        }
        return query

    def search(self, query_string, **kwargs):
        if len(query_string) == 0:
            return {
                'results': [],
                'hits': 0,
            }

        if not self.setup_complete:
            self.setup()

        search_kwargs = self.build_search_kwargs(query_string, **kwargs)
        search_kwargs['from'] = kwargs.get('start_offset', 0)

        order_fields = set()
        for order in search_kwargs.get('sort', []):
            for key in order.keys():
                order_fields.add(key)

        geo_sort = '_geo_distance' in order_fields

        end_offset = kwargs.get('end_offset')
        start_offset = kwargs.get('start_offset', 0)
        if end_offset is not None and end_offset > start_offset:
            search_kwargs['size'] = end_offset - start_offset

        try:
            raw_results = self.conn.search(search_kwargs,
                                           index=self.index_name,
                                           doc_type='modelresult')
        except (requests.RequestException, pyelasticsearch.ElasticHttpError) as e:
            if not self.silently_fail:
                raise

            self.log.error("Failed to query Elasticsearch using '%s': %s", query_string, e)
            raw_results = {}

        return self._process_results(raw_results,
            highlight=kwargs.get('highlight'),
            result_class=kwargs.get('result_class', SearchResult),
            distance_point=kwargs.get('distance_point'), geo_sort=geo_sort)

    def build_search_kwargs(self, query_string, **kwargs):
        if True:
            return self.makequery(query_string)
        else:
            # call original super:
            query = super(CustomElasticBackend, self).build_search_kwargs(query_string, **kwargs)
            return query

    def build_schema(self, fields):
        content_field_name = ''
        mapping = {}

        for field_name, field_class in fields.items():
            if field_class.field_type == 'nameword':
                field_mapping = self.makemapping(field_class.index_fieldname)
            elif field_class.field_type == 'email':
                field_mapping = self.emailmapping(field_class.index_fieldname)
            else:
                field_mapping = {
                    'boost': field_class.boost,
                    'index': 'analyzed',
                    'store': 'yes',
                    'type': 'string',
                }

                if field_class.document is True:
                    content_field_name = field_class.index_fieldname

                # DRL_FIXME: Perhaps move to something where, if none of these
                #            checks succeed, call a custom method on the form that
                #            returns, per-backend, the right type of storage?
                if field_class.field_type in ['date', 'datetime']:
                    field_mapping['type'] = 'date'
                elif field_class.field_type == 'integer':
                    field_mapping['type'] = 'long'
                elif field_class.field_type == 'float':
                    field_mapping['type'] = 'float'
                elif field_class.field_type == 'boolean':
                    field_mapping['type'] = 'boolean'
                elif field_class.field_type == 'ngram':
                    field_mapping['analyzer'] = "ngram_analyzer"
                elif field_class.field_type == 'edge_ngram':
                    field_mapping['analyzer'] = "edgengram_analyzer"
                elif field_class.field_type == 'location':
                    field_mapping['type'] = 'geo_point'

                # The docs claim nothing is needed for multivalue...
                # if field_class.is_multivalued:
                #     field_data['multi_valued'] = 'true'

                if field_class.stored is False:
                    field_mapping['store'] = 'no'

                # Do this last to override `text` fields.
                if field_class.indexed is False or hasattr(field_class, 'facet_for'):
                    field_mapping['index'] = 'not_analyzed'

                if field_mapping['type'] == 'string' and field_class.indexed:
                    field_mapping["term_vector"] = "with_positions_offsets"

                    if not hasattr(field_class, 'facet_for') and not field_class.field_type in('ngram', 'edge_ngram'):
                        field_mapping["analyzer"] = "snowball"

            mapping[field_class.index_fieldname] = field_mapping

        return (content_field_name, mapping)


class CustomElasticSearchEngine(ElasticsearchSearchEngine):
    backend = CustomElasticBackend


class NameWordField(NgramField):
    field_type = 'nameword'


class EmailField(NgramField):
    field_type = 'email'
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but can you explain, where to find this setting? I was searching for an option like this.

Comment: do you use custom data mappings? normally elasticsearch will create data mappings automatically for you. You have to setup custom data mappings beforehand and there you can specify the exact parameters to your tokenizers. In haystack you can achieve this with custom types and your own backend.

Comment: No, I don't use something custom. Do you know a page, where I can learn how to write a custom backend for haystack based on elasticsearch?